# flutter audio play delay

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, avaudioplayer

I am using the [`audioplayers` package](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) to play my mp3 audio files that are stored in firebase cloud storage.  There is a significant delay for both Android and iOS and only just slightly faster in Android.  I have since moved all my audio sound files to local asset.

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(mode: PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY);

play(String url) async {
int result = await audioPlayer.play(url);

if (result == 1) {
  // success
  print('success');
 }
}
```

Just a few days ago, I tested with the audio player in iOS Swift and play some audio files from firebase cloud storage but I did't encounter any significant delay due to buffering and it was a lot faster.

I need to find a way to get around this as I have many audio files and they need to be stored in the network.  Anyone of you have encountered similar issues and do you have any good suggestions?

Comment: Well there's [this](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/pull/355/commits/40aa95fa3509547dda8315192050f7e838b74f66) open pull request that should fix delay on iOS. that hasn't reached release version. Also there's [this](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/issues/161) discussion on big initial lag. Finally there's [this](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/issues/161) issue.

Comment: you try with cache? https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/blob/master/doc/audio_cache.md

Comment: @om-ha, thanks for this info!  So I am now waiting eagerly for the pull request to be approved and released!

Comment: @om-ha, I just made modifications to AudioPlayersPlugin.m and that sure helps, you can put that as the answer and I will mark that as correct.

Comment: @DarylWong Thanks for confirming this. If you've made any other changes feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Hey @DarylWong, just letting you know there have been new changes to the library regarding this. Check them out! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Made this [second PR](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/pull/396) that addresses few shortcomings of the [first original PR](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/pull/355/commits/40aa95fa3509547dda8315192050f7e838b74f66). Both are merged into master branch of [audioplayers](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers).

My PR changes are:

- `playbackRate` is always used in `playImmediatelyAtRate` instead of constant values -- initially set by the library to `_defaultPlaybackRate` i.e. `1.0`
- `playImmediatelyAtRate` is added to `resume` method as well, not just `play`

#### Original Solution

This is the final code that helped solving the audio play delay for the OP:

#### in `play` & `resume` method

```
AVPlayer *player = playerInfo[@"player"];

float playbackRate = [playerInfo[@"rate"] floatValue];

if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
    [player playImmediatelyAtRate:playbackRate];
} else {
    [player play];
}
```

So calling `[player playImmediatelyAtRate:playImmediatelyAtRate:playbackRate]` instead of `[player play];` seems to fix the issue.

<strike>So far it hasn't been merged into the pub and is still an open</strike> the [first incomplete PR](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/pull/355/commits/40aa95fa3509547dda8315192050f7e838b74f66) has been merged, [second PR](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/pull/396) as well.

#### Original comment:

There's [this](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/pull/355/commits/40aa95fa3509547dda8315192050f7e838b74f66) open pull request that should fix delay on iOS. that hasn't reached release version. Also there's [this](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/issues/161) discussion on big initial lag.

Comment: I am facing the delayed issue in iOS in `audioplayers: ^0.20.1` @om-ha

Comment: I see you commented on the original issue after this comment from maintainers: **[Closing this due to reports of this being fixed on newer versions. Feel free to open a new issue in case of this still happening](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues/161#issuecomment-807554690)**

Comment: If they do not respond to your comment there, open a new issue with an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and some debug info and context to allow the maintainers/community assist you in your issue.

Comment: I am just playing audio from the network and the extension is mp3 and wav. @om-ha