# Flutter audioplayers sound delay

Tags: ios, flutter, delay, audio-player

I am creating an app which uses `audioplayers` package for playing audio files and initially the audio plays perfectly but after few more rounds the audio starts playing after a delay (like 5 seconds or even longer).

This is an issue I guess many are facing as there are ton of questions but no proper answers to it. This is one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59579699/14449776) I found but the issue still persist i guess. If anyone has a workaround for this problem please share here

I am using a real iOS device (not tested on android device), flutter version 2.0.1, stable channel

Comment: Does anyone finds a solution for this problem, I still get this problem. Is there any solution for that?